# How can I send api calls from my plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, rest-api, errors, api

I have a collection of REST APIs that our android app uses. We use POSTMAN to send requests and troubleshoot them. Now, I am working on a plugin where I am trying to send API calls to all the endpoints automatically that are in my POSTMAN collections, and then I want the plugin to return me the endpoints which are getting an error status (A status without 200).

Any suggestions or any idea of how I can achieve that? Sorry if I sounded nerdy :)

Comment: 200 is not an error status, `HTTP 200` is the OK status aka success. Did you mean to type `500`? There is no code in your question and it's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking how to make a HTTP request in your android application? Or how to authenticate remotely? Please edit your question to state clearly and unambiguously the specific question you have, avoid being vague or ambiguous, and use concrete facts and specific examples. Also include code. e.g. don't say "endpoints" instead name them and give them URLs

Answer (score 0):

You can check this:

```
$api_endpoint = 'https://url_to_API';
$api_args     = array(
   'method'  => 'GET',
   'headers' => array( 'Accept' => 'application/json', 'any' => 'other' )
);
$queries      = array(
   'your_query'   => 1,
   'another_query'   => 5,
);

$api_endpoint = add_query_arg( $queries, $api_endpoint );
$response     = wp_remote_request( $api_endpoint, $api_args );
$response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response )
$data      = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );
```

Also you can access to the response code in this way: `$response['response']['code'];`

I didn't try it but I have found this resources I think it can be usefull for you:

[add_query_arg()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/)

[wp_remote_request()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_request/)

[wp_remote_retrieve_response_code()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_retrieve_response_code/)

[wp_remote_retrieve_body()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_retrieve_body/)

Hope it works for you :)
I am waiting to know if it has worked correctly for you, because I think is a very interesting issue.